# Create a rounded inflated square in illustrator / photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, path

[image: Rounded Inflated Square]

I am wondering how to create a path for this inflated square shape in illustrator or photoshop... btw how is is the shape called?

Comment: Name wise I'd say its a specimen in the family of [superellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).

Comment: I do not mind helping you, even showing what you should do but I would like to see you show me what you have tried before I show you how

Comment: I tried drawing using vector tools and i tried using rounded corner rectangle and then add anchor points.. but these methods are probably not balanced/mathematical at all... newbie here. thanks. haha

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/06/ios-7-icon-squircle/

interesting article after joojaa's comment.

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator:

1. Draw a circle with the Ellipse Tool
2. Select the circle and go to `Effect > Warp > Inflate` 
   [image]
3. Adjust the settings to the desired result (make sure preview is on), apply the settings.
4. Expand the resulting shape `Object > Expand` 
   [image]
5. You may need to rotate the resulting shape

Play with the settings in the inflate effect dialog box, results will vary.